# Линейная интерполяция для рассчета траектории движения обьекта на canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, численные-методы, html5-canvas

Пытаюсь написать свою игру на canvas, но никак не могу нормально рассчитать траекторию полета снарядов при выстреле. По задумке - снаряд летит с фиксированной скоростью по вектору от текущих координат игрока до координат мыши, пока не достигнет края canvas'a и не будет удален. С моим текущим кодом снаряды двигаются по параболе и не в ту точку. Где я допустил ошибку? Может есть более эффективный вариант рассчитать траекторию?
Код :

Добавление нового снаряда при выстреле

```
  bullets.push({ pos: [x, y],       
                           dir: 'forward',
                           angle : angle,  // наклон спрайта
                           from : { x: player.pos[0], y: player.pos[1] },
                           to : { x: mousePos.x, y: mousePos.y},
                           sprite: new Sprite('img/sprites.png', [0, 39], [18, 8]) });
```

Изменение скорости

```
bullet.pos[0] += bulletSpeed * dt; //  увеличиваю x
  bullet.pos[1] += linearInterpolation(bullet.from.x, bullet.to.x,bullet.from.y, bullet.to.y, bullet.pos[0]) * dt  ;  //  увеличиваю y
```

Интерполяция

```
function linearInterpolation(x0,x1,y0,y1,x) {
    return ((x - x0) * (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)) + y0;
}
```

Обновленный код :

```
    if(input.isDown('SPACE') &&
           !isGameOver &&
           Date.now() - lastFire > 50) {
            var x = player.pos[0] + player.sprite.size[0] / 2;
            var y = player.pos[1] + player.sprite.size[1] / 2;
            let max = Math.max(Math.abs(x), Math.abs(y));
            bullets.push({ pos: [x, y],
                           dir: 'forward',
                           angle : angle,
                           to : { x: mousePos.x/max, y: mousePos.y/max},
                           sprite: new Sprite('img/sprites.png', [0, 39], [18, 8])  });
        lastFire = Date.now();
    }
}
function updateEntities(dt) {
       player.sprite.update(dt);
        for(var i=0; i<bullets.length; i++) {
        var bullet = bullets[i];
        switch(bullet.dir) {
              default:
            bullet.pos[0] += bullet.to.x ;
            bullet.pos[1] += bullet.to.y ;

        }

          if(bullet.pos[1] < 0 || bullet.pos[1] > canvas.height ||
           bullet.pos[0] > canvas.width) {
            bullets.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: какая-то странная формула для линейной интерполяции.. почему интерполируется только вторая координата?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/995314/188366

Comment: @StrangerintheQ , Я не сильно разобрался в интерполяции, думал можно найти только y, зная начало,конец и нужный x? Я попробовал сделать как у Вас , но все равно в нужную точку снаряды не летят. Я добавил обновленный код в конец вопроса, можете подсказать что я сделал не так?