# Стрельба шарами в правильном направлении

Tags: javascript

мне нужно сделать так, что б каждый новый шар вылетал в ту сторону, куда указывает моя стрелка (стрелка поворачивается на колесеко мыши). Все до чего я додумался, это использовать теорему Пифагора, но тоже не вышло.

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        r = 5,
        x,
        cursor = document.createElement("DIV"),
        arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-arrow-up")[0],
        canvasPositionX = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().x,
        canvasPositionY = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().y,
        wheelCounter;
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 500;
    document.body.style.cursor = "none";
    cursor.classList.add("divCursor");
    document.body.appendChild(cursor);
    cursor.appendChild(arrow)
    class Ball {
        constructor(x, y, r, color) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.r = r;
            this.color = color;
            this.dx = wheelCounter;
            this.dy = -wheelCounter;
            this.animate();
        }
        drawBall() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
            ctx.clearRect(this.x - this.r - 4, this.y - this.r - 4, this.r + 16, this.r + 16);
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        animate() {
            this.drawBall();
            if (this.x + this.dx > canvas.width - this.r || this.x + this.dx < this.r) {
                this.dx = -this.dx;
                canvas.style.boxShadow = `inset 0px 0px 35px 0px rgb(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)},${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)},${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)})`;
            }
            if (this.y + this.dy > canvas.height - this.r || this.y + this.dy < this.r) {
                this.dy = -this.dy;
                canvas.style.boxShadow = `inset 0px 0px 35px 0px rgb(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)},${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)},${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)})`;
            }
            this.x += this.dx;
            this.y += this.dy;
            requestAnimationFrame(() => this.animate());
        }
    }
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
        cursor.style.animation = "cursorPressed 1s ease-in-out infinite";
        x = setInterval(() => {
            r++;
        }, 200);
    })
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
        cursor.style.animation = "cursor 1s ease-in-out infinite";
        clearInterval(x);
        if (r > 7) {
            new Ball(e.clientX - canvasPositionX, e.clientY - canvasPositionY, 8, `rgb(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)},${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)},${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)})`);
        } else {
            new Ball(e.clientX - canvasPositionX, e.clientY - canvasPositionY, r, `rgb(${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)},${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)},${Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)})`);
        }
        r = 5;
    })
    //cursor
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        cursor.style.left = `${e.clientX - 15}px`
        cursor.style.top = `${e.clientY - 15}px`
    })
    window.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => {
        console.log(wheelCounter)
        if (e.deltaY < 0) {
            wheelCounter += 5;
        } else {
            wheelCounter -= 5
        }
        cursor.style.transform = `rotateZ(${wheelCounter}deg)`;
    })
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/995314/188366